# Crash in d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, openssl

I have a small `VC++` code to load an ASN.1 `.der` file and read its `private` key. It compiles and runs fine, but it crashes at function `d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp`.

**Tools Used:**

- Visual Studio 2008 [V90]
- OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

I have also tested the certificate to check if it was corrupted

**Testing certificate:**

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl rsa -in  private.der -check -inform DER
RSA key ok
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>
```

Below is the code for the project.

**Thing I have tried**:

- Win32OpenSSL-0_9_8zg (but same issue), OpenSSL 1.0.1
- Tried linking libeay to MD, MDd, MT
- Set flags to Generate /MAP, /MAPINFO:EXPORTS ,/ASSEMBLYDEBUG
- exported to VS2010 project and compiled with openssl32 for VS2010

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ret;
    RSA *pkey=NULL;//RSA_new();
    RSA *rsa =NULL;//RSA_new();

    unsigned char text[2048/8] = "this is a test string";
    unsigned char  encrypted[4098]={};
    unsigned char decrypted[4098]={};

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();   
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();  
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();  
    ERR_load_ERR_strings();

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/Public/private.der","rb");

    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp(fp, &pkey);   // <<< CRASH
    }
    else
    {
        //return "Error::Unable to read private key file";
    }

    if (rsa)
    {
        // RSA is good
        ret = RSA_private_encrypt(RSA_size(pkey), text, encrypted, pkey, RSA_NO_PADDING);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            //return "Error::Failed to encrypt the data";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fp);
        //return "Error::Failed to get *RSA Handle1";
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

**Second attempt**

I am facing issue with importing private key from ASN.1 `.der` file to a `.pem` file.

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl rsa -in private.der -inform DER -out privatepem.pem -outform PEM 

writing RSA key
```

Now, I have .PEM file which have private key in Base64 Form which i will convert it to RSA *rsa; structure.

```c
int main()
{
    int ret;
    RSA *pkey=NULL;//RSA_new();
    RSA *rsa =NULL;//RSA_new();

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/Public/privatepem.pem","r");

    if(PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL) == NULL)  // <<<CRASH
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", "Error Reading public key");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", "Private key Imported");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the new code operating on `.pem` files has a crash while copying to RSA structure at `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`.

Why am I getting the crash? Is there something I am missing to do, may be initialization of some sort or something wrong with the key?

Comment: You might want to read [this mail thread](http://marc.info/?t=136113209000001&r=1&w=1), especially [this specific mail](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=136119026821004&w=1).

Comment: I just tried combination as Steve explained OPENSSL_malloc behavior in the mail but it still have same crash point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem was solved by replacing the OpenSSL binaries.**

Code worked without any changes. 
Project had prebuild dependencies of OpenSSL which was from unknown source.

So just by replacing dependencies from "https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html" it worked like a charm.

:)
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

See the warnings at [d2i_X509](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html#WARNINGS). This code will attempt to free (or reuse parts of) the `pkey` object:

```c
if (fp != NULL) 
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp(fp, &pkey);   /* CRASH */
```

OpenSSL is not exactly known for validating parameters before taking actions on them :)

Instead, use:

```c
if (fp != NULL) 
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp(fp, NULL);
```

Or:

```c
RSA* pkey = RSA_new();
...

if (fp != NULL) 
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp(fp, &pkey);
```

Also see [Seg fault from d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Seg-fault-from-d2i-RSAPrivateKey-fp-td43785.html) on the OpenSSL Users mailing list.

---

As for the crash after using the API as directed, then it sounds like you have other issues. Since OpenSSL is cross-platofrm, its "write once, run everywhere". Port the OpenSSL-based TLS logic to Linux, and get a memory checker like Valgrind on it.

Comment: It was least expected for the bug to be in OpenSSL repo. Your solution is very accurate, It would had helped a lot in finding the root cause couple of days back.